# SQL Select Entries with same Column Values

Tags: sql

Imagine that I have a column like this:

```
Var: 1, 1, , 3, 2
-
Name: Ben, John, Josh, Bill
```

How can I select Entries with the same `VAR` column Value? Like, if I want entries with value `1` in the `VAR` column, it will give me `Ben` and `Josh`.

Comment: It sounds like you're storing comma-separated data in a column. **Don't do that!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you records having multiple records of the same `VAR`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a.Var = b.Var
            GROUP   BY Var
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af3a1e/2)

Another way to solve this is by using `JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Var
            FROM    TableName b
            GROUP   BY Var
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.Var = b.Var
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af3a1e/3)

But adds a little confusion when you add this line: *"..if I want entries with value 1 in the VAR column, it will give me: Ben and Josh"* -- Do you want to specify `VAR` or not? [Like this demo <<](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af3a1e/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT name
  FROM table1
 WHERE var IN (SELECT MIN(var)
                FROM table1
               GROUP BY var
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c42fae/3)** demo.

Answer (score 0):

this question is confusing, does a select not work?

```
select name from theTable
where var = 1
```